# log4j second logger erroring

Tags: log4j

Why does my second logger error but the first doesn't?

Error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (StatQueryDobadoCategory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

This is the log4j.properties:

```
log4j.category.ThingsPerMinuteGraphCategory=DEBUG, ThingsPerMinuteGraphAppender
log4j.appender.ThingsPerMinuteGraphAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ThingsPerMinuteGraphAppender.File=./logs/ThingsPerMinuteGraph.log
log4j.appender.ThingsPerMinuteGraphAppender.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.ThingsPerMinuteGraphAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.ThingsPerMinuteGraphAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ThingsPerMinuteGraphAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %m
log4j.additivity.ThingsPerMinuteGraphCategory=false

log4j.category.StatQueryDobadoCategory=DEBUG, StatQueryDobadoAppender
log4j.appender.StatQueryDobadoAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.StatQueryDobadoAppender.File=./logs/StatQueryDobadoCategory.log
log4j.appender.StatQueryDobadoAppender.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.StatQueryDobadoAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.StatQueryDobadoAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.StatQueryDobadoAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %m
log4j.additivity.StatQueryDobadoCategory=false
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the log4j.properties cannot be accessed by the library.

1. If you use log4j just for a java project, put the property file into your source folder
2. If you use log4j for a j2ee project, like spring+hibernate, put log4j.properties into WEB-INF folder and set the property file's path in the project's property file

   ```
   <context-param>
   <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```